# How to replace spaces with dashes from function argument?

Tags: bash

Would like something like:

/mm/dd/my-feature-name

i have started to build a bash function

```
cob() {
    now=$(date +"%m/%d")
    git cob myname/$now/$1
}
```

but i would like a way to dasherize the input following `cob`

then i can type `cob "my awesome branch name"` and it would run
`git co -b name/08/15/my-awesome-branch-name`

Comment: Given that the lifecycle of a typical development branch in Git is not as temporal as a day, I'm curious as to why you would want this.  It's *doable*, but I want to understand the rationale behind it.

Comment: Why not just type `cob my-awesome-branch-name`?

Comment: @Makoto i tend to have around 15 open branches locally at a given time, whether if i just jotting down ideas(in code) or starting on features and blocked on others. Its nice to know which ones i started at which times just built right into the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume 'dasherize' means 'replace whitespace with hyphens' rather than anything related to dasher.  Just do:

```
cob() {
   name=name/$(date +%m/%d)/${1// /-}
   git checkout -b "$name"
}
```

You'd probably be happier squeezing whitespace and using:

```
cob() { git checkout -b "name/$(date +%m/%d)/$(echo $1 | tr -s ' ' -)"; }
```